# What will happen to the current Bowl games when the playoff system commences?

Tags: american-football, collegiate

In 2014, the NCAA will switch from the current Bowl Game system for Division 1 football to a four-team playoff format wherein the top 4 teams will compete for the championship. Will the current Bowl Games (e.g: Rose Bowl, Cotton Bowl, Capitol One Bowl) still be played when this format change happens or will they disappear? It seems like if they disappear, only four teams would be competing at the end of the season, rather than the multitude of games that currently take place in the Bowl Game format. If it is the case that the Bowl Games no longer exist, are they also being replaced with another system to allow more teams opportunities for post-season play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NCAA](http://www.ncaa.com/news/football/article/2012-06-30/answers-about-footballs-new-playoff) states that the National Championship game will become the "Super Bowl" of college football...meaning any city can bid to host.

Two bowls will rotate among six in existence to host the playoff semifinals. The other four bowls who will not host a playoff semifinal in a given year will be host to bowl games among the best non-playoff teams.

> Will the current Bowl Games (e.g: Rose Bowl, Cotton Bowl, Capitol One Bowl) still be played when this format change happens or will they disappear?

Yes, current bowl games will still be played.

---

> **Where will the games be played?**
>
> The two semifinals will rotate among
>   six sites. The current BCS games are the Rose Bowl (Pasadena, Calif.),
>   Sugar Bowl (New Orleans), Fiesta Bowl (Glendale, Ariz.) and Orange
>   Bowl (Miami). The Cotton Bowl, now played at the state-of-the-art
>   Cowboys Stadium in Arlington, Texas, has to be considered a
>   front-runner to land one of the other two spots. Candidates for the
>   other one? Try Atlanta and Jacksonville, Fla.
>
> The championship game will become college football’s Super Bowl. Any
>   city can bid on it, even ones that host the semifinals and those that
>   have not been traditional bowl sites. Expect most to be played in dome
>   stadiums or warm-weather sites.

Comment: Does this also refer to all the smaller Bowl Games, like the Little Caesar's Pizza Bowl? I couldn't find anything saying either way on these.

Comment: As far as I understood, the other bowls not included with the playoff will continue untouched. Just speculation, but if the Little Caesar's Pizza Bowl is pushed out of Bowl season, it would most likely be due to bowl organizers and sponsoring vs. being excluded due to the playoff system.